# sql insert with subselects

Tags: sql, db2

I have SQL Query whitch looks loke this:

```
INSERT INTO TABEL1 (val1,val2,val3,....,val10,val11)
VALUES (......
(SELECT VAL1 FROM TABELE2 WHERE...),
(SELECT VAL2 FROM TABELE2 WHERE...),
(SELECT VAL3 FROM TABELE2 WHERE...)
.....)
```

Witch better implementaion of such insert you can suggest?

Comment: Are the `where` clauses all the same?

Comment: yes they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1,val2,val3,....,val10,val11)
SELECT val1, val2, val3, ...
FROM table2 
WHERE...
```

If you want some additional constants then just add them to the select:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2, val3, ...., val10, val11)
SELECT val1, val2, val3, 'some info', 42, ...
FROM table2 
WHERE...
```

Comment: table1 is not a total copy of tabel2, it has some other values

Comment: @big_buka: you can control which values you want from table2. If you want something different than you need to supply **way** more details.